# Why value types can't be null

Tags: c#, .net, null, clr, value-type

I know that it is possible to have Nullable value types that wraps the value type and gives ability to store null. 
But is there a technical reason do not allow the value type to be null or the reason is only conceptual?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

A reference type is storeed as a reference (like a pointer) to an object instance.
`null` means a reference that isn't pointing to an instance of an object.

Value types are stored as the values themselves, without any references.
Therefore, it doesn't make sense to have a `null` value type—the value type *by definition* contains a value.

`Nullable<T>` is a value type with a `HasValue` flag that can be `false` to indicate that there is no value.  It still has a value (when `HasValue` is `false`, `Value` is `default(T)`), but the `HasValue` flag tells you to ignore the value.
It has nothing to do with `null`, except that the CLR automatically unboxes `null` boxed values to a `Nullable<T>` with `HasValue` set to `false`.

Comment: we can make variables nullable using ? operator. for example, int? x = null;

Comment: @Shekhar: He realizes that.  It has nothing to do with `null`.

Answer (score 1):

A value type like 'Int32' is stored using thirty-two bits of storage.  There are precisely 4,294,967,296 values that may be represented by 32 bits, and an Int32 can hold 4,294,967,296 different values.  If -2,147,483,648 were not a valid Int32 value, it might be possible to use that to represent "null", but the fact that its binary representation isn't all zeroes would complicate things.  By contrast, the number of possible bit combinations in a reference type far exceeds the number of possible valid references, so there's no difficulty reserving a bit combination to represent "null".

Comment: Any reference (article) to what you are explaining ? I am still not clear about the idea you placed.