# Proper way to compare integers

Tags: c#

I'm not an expert in C# but know that I should not simply use `==` when comparing strings. Is there a similar `.Equals` method that I should use when comparing ints?

For example, I would like to do something like:

```
if (someInt == 2) {}
```

Is that acceptable in C#?

Comment: Nothing wrong with that.

Comment: There is also [`Int32.Equals`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tf6tw08e(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @UweKeim That would be appropriate if you wanted to know which was greater than the other.  If you just want to know if they're equal, use the tool designed to do just that.

Comment: Int is a value type, so it can not be null. Two useful links => Value Types: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6521101/why-value-types-cant-be-null

Comment: I can't see why not, though I'm not a pro myself. On a footnote, int can't be null in c# unless explicitly declared as nullable.

Comment: Why do you think you shouldn't use `==` when comparing strings? If you want to know whether two strings are exactly equal, that's fine. This isn't Java :)

Comment: @KJPrice I would do a msdn search on the difference between `.Equals vs ==` there is a difference between object equality and value equality..

Comment: Good stuff to think about. Thanks everyone for your comments.

Comment: @MethodMan The difference between `object.Equals` and `==` has nothing to do with object equality and value equality.  The only difference between the two is that `object.Equals` does a virtual dispatch on the first operand whereas `==` determines the implementation to use entirely based on the compile time type of both operands, and that any given type doesn't necessarily need to provide the same behavior for either operation (even though they should).  Whether the compile time or runtime types of any of the involved values are value types or references types is irrelevant.

Comment: either way I think that the OP gets the gist of what he was asking was a negative assumption.. cheers...

Comment: The only time you need to really worry about `==` not returning `true` for two built-in types that appear to be equal are when precision comes into play, like with `double`. Two `double`s can appear to be the same, but not be equal due to precision. As others have said, `==` is perfectly valid for ints, shorts, longs, strings (assuming case/culture sensitivity), bytes, etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I should not simply use == when comparing strings

Why not? (Assuming another culture or some other non-default comparison mechanism is appropriate for you.)  It's a perfectly sensible operator for strings, just like it is for ints.  It tells you whether the two values are equal, just as one would expect.

It's not the *only* way to compare two string or ints for equality, but it's certainly valid one.

Comment: I think it is possible the OP is confusing using == with Objects and using with strings and value types.

Comment: Indeed. C#'s `==` is not like Java's `==`, which cannot be overridden to make semantic sense on reference types

Comment: If I remember correctly doing a .Equals(x) where x is a null string object throws an exception as well, so `==` works better if there are null values.

Answer (score 3):

As `int` is a value type, it cannot be `null`.

Hence you can use `==` just fine.

However, if you have an `MyInteger` class (a wrapper class for value type `int`, that inherits from an `Object` type) that can be a `null` object, in which it does not contain an `int` within it. [See this MSDN regarding Boxing and Unboxing, where an `int` is boxed and assigned to an `object`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx).

Back to the question, you can use == just fine for `int` types, here are a few other alternatives:

**a. `CompareTo` method**

e.g: `5.CompareTo(6) //returns -1`
  This will return -1 if first int is smaller, 0 is they are equal, and 1 if first int is larger. This method is similar to `< > ==` operators.

**b. `Int32.Equals` method** 
   This is identical to `==` as it returns a true/false boolean. [See an example from MSDN here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tf6tw08e(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2). However **there is a difference of this method compared to ==** for a **boxed int**, as Jon Skeet detailed in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22234776/int32-equals-vs-operator), this is related to the boxing and unboxing I mentioned

Comment: .NET has no `Integer` class.  If you're referring to a custom class that you create, then that would be different from the boxing/unboxing that the language does, as that only applies to storing a value type in `object` or a container of an interface type that it implements.  C# also has no definition for the term "primitive type"; if you mean value type, then just say that.

Comment: Thanks for the examples of the other available methods!

Comment: @Servy thanks, I've edited the post to reflect this. (Java background, apologies)

Comment: Note that if one really wants to have a nulllable int then you should be using the `Nullable<T>` type, not creating your own custom wrapper for an int.  Now, if you need reference semantics as opposed to value semantics for an int, then it can be appropriate.  You also haven't addressed the inappropriate use of the term "primitive" or the fact that you're referring to boxing with respect to something that isn't actually boxing.

Comment: @Servy putting an int inside any class should still be considered boxing, as the MSDN docs say so here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx in which the example it highlights is that the int gets 'boxed' to an Object type, which MyInteger inherits from. As for the word primitive, C# represents all primitive types as objects, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228360%28v=vs.90%29.aspx. I have used it inappropriately, i will edit.

Comment: @matrixanomaly If you read you own link, it will tell you what boxing is.  When it says `object` it means the *type* object, not any object instance.  It is a specific language feature.  Creating a custom class with an `int` field is not using that language feature, so linking to it is going to be highly confusing to other readers.  One could argue "boxing", as a general CS term, would apply to both situations, but that is going to be confusing if you use a different definition of the term than the C# language uses.

Comment: As for the other link, that's a C# for java article; it's using Java terms.  If you mean value types, then say value types, because that's the appropriate C# term.  If you're intending to talk about built in types, then use *that* term.  Both are well defined terms in the context of C#.

Answer (score 2):

I think I can clear up a little confusion here. The choice of using .Equals over == in `String` is actually from Java. In Java, `String` is wrapped and treated like an object, which can cause some issues, including null pointer exceptions. This doesn't arise in c# however, because `String` is a basic type, and `String.Equals(a, b)` is defined as `a == b`. String.Equals does give you some options by allowing you to add a comparison type. This is a slight advantage to String.Equals, but in no way should you always use one over the other. However, I felt it was necessary to note that String.Equals should be used in Java as the two languages are very similar and could be confused by a beginner.
That being said, the above answers regarding `int a == int b` and `Int32.Equals` are all valid, I would use `==` more often for ints because it is a more commonly accepted practice.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation. That makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can absolutely use == for Strings in C#, we have operator overrides.

Answer (score 0):

Personnally I like better using .Equal()
Because it will check both value and data type.

So int 200 != string "200" != double 200 .. etc

And it will not throwing exception like using == over 2 different type of data.

example :
int x = 200;
string y = "200";

if(x==y){ } //==> this will throw exception and block execution