# Unable to check if integer is equal to zero

Tags: c#

[image]

I just need it to check if the variable "remaining" equals 0

Comment: = it not same as ==

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Related - [Proper way to compare integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30086743/proper-way-to-compare-integers)

Answer (score 2):

To check equality in C# use == operator.

```
if(remaining == 0){
    // write your logic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the == operator

```
if(remaining == 0){
    // write your logic
}
```

The == operator checks whether the LHS = RHS or not whereas
= is an assignment operator it is used to assign values like int a = 10;