# Return null in the method

Tags: c#, null, double

I'm trying to make converter which converting metrics to imperials. Also i'm doing unit test for it. If i pass negative value, the method supposed to return null. Is it possible to return null from the method which returns double.

```
public double mgToGrain(double mg)     
{

     double grain = mg * myValues["mgTograin"];
     return grain;
     if (mg < 0) {
         return null;
     } 
}

    `
```

Comment: Make it return `double?` and well...fix your code, the check should be before first return...

Comment: Regardless of whether you *can*, I *wouldn't*. I'd rather throw an exception or return some optional entity around a double. That way it indicates to the client that an error result is possible, and they should be able to handle it

Comment: @Brian but then he may need to introduce a `TryMgToGrain()` method that does not throw and returns a `bool`...hmmmm....

Comment: This question is absolutely not a duplicate of "what's a nullable type". It is a lot more specific, because the return type (`double`) has features that are missing from other built-in types. Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A possible alternative to `double?` in case you have to stick to `double` is `double.NaN` (**Not a Number**):

```
public double mgToGrain(double mg) {
  if (mg < 0)
    return double.NaN;
  else
    return mg * myValues["mgTograin"];
}    

...

double x = ...

if (double.IsNaN(mgToGrain(x))) {  
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Value types can't be null. You have to use `Nullable` type, either by returning `Nullable<double>` or `double?`

```
public double? mgToGrain(double mg)     
{           
   if (mg < 0) 
   {
       return null;
   }

   double grain = mg * myValues["mgTograin"];

   return grain;
}
```

Also fixed your code as you return from function before `if`.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6521120/2043144) you have really good explanation about value types and null.

Comment: Please fix it correctly and make the function bail out before doing the calculation.

Comment: Thank you for help.

Answer (score 2):

Check this article [Nullable Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx)

```
public double? mgToGrain(double mg)     
{
     return null;
}
```

Comment: Cheers. That helped

Answer (score 2):

You cannot return `null` from a method declared to return `double`. You have several options for making an API here:

- **Return `double?`, AKA `Nullable<double>`** - this approach would require callers to check the value for `null` prior to using it, or apply null coalescing to deal with invalid return values
- **Throw an exception** - This approach would let you continue returning `double`. The callers who want to handle errors would need a `try`/`catch` block
- **Return a value indicating success or failure, and setting conversion result in an `out` parameter** - this would be similar to `TryParse` and `TryGetValue` APIs in .NET.

**Note:** You need to check for negative before returning from a method. In your current implementation the code that checks for negatives is unreachable.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to define your result as nullable and it should work (and also move `return grain;` to the end, otherwise it returns too fast):

```
public double? mgToGrain(double mg)
{
    double grain = mg * myValues["mgTograin"];
    if (mg < 0) {
        return null;
    }
    return grain;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Others have posted the obvious solution in returning a *nullable* double, but there is another solution to consider.

An alternate, and perhaps better, solution is to throw an exception if the input is out of range. This has the same effect with regards to not returning any specific value, but it also provides feedback to the caller about what specifically they did wrong when they called the method.

```
public double mgToGrain(double mg)     
{
    double grain = mg * myValues["mgTograin"];
    if (mg < 0) {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("mg must be greater than or equal to 0.");
    }
    return grain;
}
`
```